# Which column(s) to create index on for a query across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, indexing

given the following query, and I am asked to create an index to speed up this specific query. However, I am not sure which column(s) to create the index on, since the query uses multiple tables and columns. My inclination is to create the index on the PassingStats table, since it seems to be used the most in the WHERE section of the query, but I am not sure. Should this be an unclustered index?

Here is the query:

````
SELECT P.name, R.position, T.mascot, G.date, Stats.touchdowns
FROM Player P, PlayedFor R, Team T, Game G, PassingStats Stats
WHERE P.pid = R.pid AND R.pid = Stats.pid
    AND Stats.touchdowns >= 6
    AND (Stats.tid = G.vtid OR Stats.tid = G.htid) 
    AND (Stats.season = G.season AND Stats.week = G.week)
    AND T.tid = Stats.tid AND R.tid = Stats.tid```

Thanks in advance!
````

Comment: An index is created on an individual table, not many.  One assumes from the "id" columns that you already are using some primary key columns and these are automatically/necessarily indexed.  [Unclustered indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) are only implemented for non-integer primary keys, so the answer to that would require a deeper understanding of the entire schema and would not be the focus of indexes for a single query optimization.

Comment: What database are you using? You tagged sqlite and MySQL.

Comment: If using sqlite, the sqlite3 shell has [a command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) for suggesting indexes.

Comment: Hi guys! I technically don't know what database I am using, since this is for a general database course I am taking at my university. I think it is probably safe to assume sqlite though, since for our programming assignment we used python's sqlite3 module

Answer (score 1):

before adding index, lets refactor first your query if it improves. seems there's a disconnection between your joined tables. please try below query.

```
SELECT p.name
    , r.position
    , t1.mascot
    , t1.date
    , t1.touchdowns
FROM Player p
INNER JOIN PlayedFor r ON p.pid = r.pid
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT s.pid, t.mascot, coalesce(g1.date, g2.date) as date, s.touchdowns
        FROM PassingStats s
        INNER JOIN Team t on t.tid = s.tid
        LEFT JOIN Game g1 on s.tid = g1.vtid and s.season = g1.season and s.week = g1.week
        LEFT JOIN Game g2 on s.tid = g2.htid and s.season = g2.season and s.week = g2.week
        WHERE s.touchdowns >= 6) as t1
    ON t1.pid = r.pid
```

Comment: Hi! Do you mind explaining the disconnection in the original query? I did write the original query, so I'd love to know where I went wrong as well. Your query seems to be far more complex, and is probably correct, but I can't actually run these queries since I don't have an actual database that I'm using for these– It's just a hypothetical for a problem set for a database course

Comment: Your game table is only related to stats, but you are joining these to your other tables, that's why I group it within a subquery `t1`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JOIN .. ON ..` syntax, not the old commalist syntax.  After doing that, it will be easy to see what is used for `JOINing` versus what is used for 'filtering' (`WHERE`).

I suspect the only thing in the `WHERE` will be

```
Stats.touchdowns >= 6
```

Given that, the Optimizer is *likely* to use `Stats` as the first table, and filter on `touchdowns`.  So, have

```
INDEX(touchdowns)
```

The other tables will probably be accessed using NLJ (Nested Loop Join), one table at a time.

So, make sure there is an index (or `PRIMARY KEY`) on each subsequent table, letting it use a value from the previous table(s) to get into the next table.

`OR` is a train wreck.  I don't know what will happen to handle that.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (for each table).

Your Question is posed as an "index" question.  If, ultimately, the question is about speeding up the query, then so state.  In this case, I *may* suggest turning `OR` into `UNION`.

Simple index creation is covered here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql